# Send base64Binary SOAP parameter between Java client and PHP server

Tags: java, php, nusoap, wsimport

I have a **PHP SOAP** server (using **nuSOAP** with wsdl) that send the content of a html page. Of course, the HTML can be coded with differents encoding, but this parameter is **base64Binary type in XML**, and I receive the HTML in the "native encoding" without problems.

In order to prove, I have coded **three SOAP clients in: PHP, C# and Java 6** and with the first two I have no problem. The java client was made using **WSIMPORT 2.1** and an example of code it's like this:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream (new File ("/tmp/chinese.htm"));
BufferedReader  buffer = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (file
                                             ,"BIG5"));
String line;
String content = "";
while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null)
   content += line+"\n";

FileManagerAPI upload = new FileManagerAPI();
FileManagerAPIPortType servUpload = upload.getFileManagerAPIPort();

BigInteger result = servUpload.apiControllerServiceUploadHTML (
       "http://www.test.tmp/因此鳥哥建議您務.html", content.getBytes());
```

The **problem is that before send the HTML in base64 encoding, only the Java client encodes HTML content to UTF8** and, when PHP receives this file, the server manage it like "UTF8 archive", not like a "BIG5 file".

The question is, **how to avoid the first UTF8 encoding?** or at least do utf-8 encoding after base64, not earlier.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to convert the file from UTF-8 (I think that's the encoding of `/tmp/chinese.htm`) to BIG5 first.

To convert a file's content, read the file and re-encode it, for example with [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

```
$path = '/tmp/chinese.htm';
$buffer = file_get_contents($path);
$buffer = iconv('UTF-8', 'BIG5', $buffer);
```

The buffer `$buffer` is now re-encoded from UTF-8 into BIG5.

Comment: Thanks @hakre, although while it's true that in this particular case the iconv works perfectly, I don't trust it too in this function due to with other tests (other encodings) don't work very well. Moreover, the java client is the only performs this conversion to utf8.

Comment: Well I haven't had problems with `iconv` as long as the input encoding is correctly specified, but I don't work much with chinese encodings. In any case it's a well made library so I don't see the point why not to trust it. It's even free software which can be changed in case an error is found. But perhaps I don't see your underlying problem, so the re-encoding from UTF-8 to BIG5 is not the only problem you're facing. If you elaborate more, I perhaps can add some more hints at what to look at.

Comment: I have MongoDB to save the content of the HTML (I need to break down the structures of html to work individually with them). This database works in UTF8, for this reason I tried to use iconv to convert the "original encoding" of web page to UTF8 but when the original code has more characters than utf8, this function don't work correctly. For this reason I used a python script than converted this html to unicode before save it in MongoDB. This is the argument by which I do not trust the iconv function.

Comment: Sounds more like a general encoding problem (even I don't believe that you have characters that aren't supported by UTF-8 which is unicode), it looks more the other way round that BIG5 does not support all unicode characters (which is true). So don't re-encode unicode to BIG5 if that is the case as BIG5 is not a fitting encoding then.

Comment: The problem is that I need to maintain the "original encoding", because the HTML content is processed and stored on its web server again (replacing the previous one). I have no problem with PHP and C# clients, only Java transform the HTML to uft8 before send it.

Comment: Okay, that clarifies it for me, I thought you had a PHP problem.

Comment: On the other hand, iconv when detect an "illegal character" cut the result string. For this reason, I can't get the full content of HTML in chinese language for example.